# Google App Engine TCP/IP connection

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, tcp, connection, go

I would like to set up a couple TCP/IP connections in GAE using Go. As I've searched it is impossible to get a static IP from the app engine, but can't find much data on other limitations.

Is it possible to establish a TCP/IP connection in GAE, and if so, how long can it be used before it has to be re-established?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) that you may not open a socket from within their sandboxed environment.
Now HTTP is also based on TCP/IP, and you may "fetch" content using URLs (in Python it's urllib and urllib2, don't know much about Go). But raw SOCK_STREAM connections? NO.

regards,

Yati Sagade

Comment: URL fetching is performed using URLFetch, on all 3 platforms. Each also provides wrappers around common mechanisms - so urllib in Python App Engine is simply a wrapper around URLFetch.

Answer (score 5):

The situation has changed and as of July 2013 there is an experimental Socket service available for Java and Python. It is enabled only for paid accounts, you can only create outbound connections, and there are few other limitations. Also, [the docs says](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) that the API is not stable and may be subject to changes.

As of December 2013 there is the experimental Socket service available for Go as well. The conditions in [the relevant doc page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/) are similar to the ones for Java and Python.